# Using VMTK to convert VTK into STL and vice versa

Tags: stl, vtk

I am trying to use VMTK (The Vascular Modeling Toolkit http://www.vmtk.org/index.html) to convert a large number of VTK files into STL and vice versa. I usually use ParaView but I'm looking to reduce the possibility of human error by automating the conversion. I have no experience with Python but have experience with Matlab.

Currently, I am unable to even read the files using VMTK without an error output so I think I am using the wrong VMTK Scripts.

Does anyone have any expertise in this area?

Thank you very much.

Comment: ParaView can generate the python script of your actions. So you just need to know how to pass your file as inputs. Is it an acceptable solution for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a ParaView python script that do the same thing as you do in the GUI.

To create such script no need to know how to write python code, you can use the Python Trace:

- `Tools / Start Trace`
- default options should be OK
- do your usual actions (load a file, etc )
- `Tools / Stop Trace`.
- save it to disk
- modify it to use argument instead of hardcoded path

For instance, it may look like:

```
# trace generated using paraview version 5.8.1-1632-g0a4d2813b0

#### import the simple module from the paraview
from paraview.simple import *
#### disable automatic camera reset on 'Show'
paraview.simple._DisableFirstRenderCameraReset()

import sys
if len(sys.argv) != 2:

    raise ValueError('Please provide a filename.')

filename = sys.argv[1]
print(f'Processing {filename} ...')

# create a new 'Legacy VTK Reader'
blowvtk = LegacyVTKReader(FileNames=[filename])
...
```

- run `./pvpython myscript.py file-to-process.vtk

Of course, with more python (or other scripting tool) you can improve this to loop over a list of file instead of processing only one, etc...

Comment: Thank you, I was able to use this method to batch convert vtks to stls